# Change colors with @for loop SASS

Tags: css, loops, sass, colors, frontend

So i have a map of colors in sass which goes like

```
$form-option-colors: (
    1: rgba(242,218,177,1),
    2: rgba(222,186,133,1),
    3: rgba(255,139,107,1),
    4: rgba(237,116,83,1),
    5: rgba(245,98,140,1),
    6: rgba(148,61,112,1),
    7: rgba(49,127,163,1),
    8: rgba(39,101,130,1)
);
```

Now i wanna pass each one of these colors to a different div. I've tried to use a @for loop in sass but it keeps throwing me Compilation Errors.
This the @for loop code:

```
@for $i from 1 through 8 {
  $color: map.get($form-option-colors, $i);
  .option-#{$i} {
    color: $color;
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that i have 8 different .option containers which im iterating through

How can i make this work properly?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the *module-function* `map.get()` without importing said module.

```
@use "sass:list";
@use "sass:map";

$form-option-colors: (
    "1": rgb(242, 218, 177),
    "2": rgb(222, 186, 133),
    "3": rgb(255, 139, 107),
    "4": rgb(237, 116, 83),
    "5": rgb(245, 98, 140),
    "6": rgb(148, 61, 112),
    "7": rgb(49, 127, 163),
    "8": rgb(39, 101, 130)
);

@for $i from 1 through list.length($form-option-colors) {
  .option-#{$i} {
    color: list.nth(map.values($form-option-colors), $i);
  }
}
```

You can avoid having to import the module first by calling functions by their *global name* instead.

```
map.get() //module
map-get() //global
```

Though I'd discourage you from doing so, since Sass is going to deprecate the global functions in the future.

Also make sure you are running **Dart-Sass**.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed by importing the module. Thanks!